# How to remove "Update required" (red triangle) from top panel

Tags: indicator, applet

running ubuntu 20.04 fully updated
Lately as part of the "Indicator applet complete" I see a red triangle icon, when clicke on advises me to run "sudo apt update"
I don't need the reminder, as I generally run apt update daily, or at most every two days.
Also running sudo apt update does not clear the icon immediately, it seems to take a random wait time. Running sudo apt update results in a message that there are no updates.

`sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease 
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelebek333/kablosuz/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/unstable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done All packages are up to date.
```

Changed repository suource, and run update immediately afterwards:

$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelebek333/kablosuz/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/unstable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [506 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,642 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [8,628 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5,124 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [22.0 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [8,112 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted Translation-en [6,212 B]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [74.7 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse Translation-en [104 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1,777 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [502 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [295 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1,239 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted i386 Packages [25.3 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [176 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,152 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [733 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [379 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages [26.6 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1,330 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [188 kB]
Fetched 30.3 MB in 7s (4,266 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

Still have a red triangle in top panel

Comment: The icon on my system (MATE) is somewhat different, but I believe you are describing the indicator which tells you that there are problems in the package system, not that you need to update. What is the full output of `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Please add output of `sudo apt update` to your question. Don't just tell that "there are no updates". It looks like repositories are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you disabled main repositories. Only `security` is enabled.

Start Software & Updates application and enable all repositories there, except `proposed`.